# Comparing picturebox.image in Visual Basic

Tags: image, comparison, system.drawing

I'm trying to make a matching game in Visual Basic 2010, and to check if the chosen cards are in fact a match I want to compare the value of firstchoice.image to secondchoice.image.

The problem I am running into is that in the comparison the value of anything.image is returning as `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, therefore the comparison always returns true.

The comparison code as of right now is:

```
If FirstI Is My.Resources.circle Then
    TempOne = 1
ElseIf FirstI Is My.Resources.crescent Then
    TempOne = 2
ElseIf FirstI Is My.Resources.pentagram Then
    TempOne = 3
ElseIf FirstI Is My.Resources.square Then
    TempOne = 4
ElseIf FirstI Is My.Resources.triangle Then
    TempOne = 5
ElseIf FirstI Is My.Resources.yinyang Then
    TempOne = 6
End If

If SecondI Is My.Resources.circle Then
    TempOne = 1
ElseIf SecondI Is My.Resources.crescent Then
    TempOne = 2
ElseIf SecondI Is My.Resources.pentagram Then
    TempOne = 3
ElseIf SecondI Is My.Resources.square Then
    TempOne = 4
ElseIf SecondI Is My.Resources.triangle Then
    TempOne = 5
ElseIf SecondI Is My.Resources.yinyang Then
    TempOne = 6
End If
Debug.WriteLine(FirstI)
Debug.WriteLine(SecondI)
If TempOne = TempTwo Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

FirstI and SecondI are declared as

```
Private FirstI As Image
Private SecondI As Image
```

and are filled in with data pulled from an array of images.

```
Private Cards() As Image = {My.Resources.circle, My.Resources.crescent, My.Resources.pentagram, My.Resources.square, My.Resources.triangle, My.Resources.yinyang, My.Resources.circle, My.Resources.crescent, My.Resources.pentagram, My.Resources.square, My.Resources.triangle, My.Resources.yinyang}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I wouldn't try to directly compare objects/values, I would simply compare state.  Keep a FirstIIndex and SecondIIndex (as Integer) that are index integers from 0 to Cards.Length.  When you set that value, set the image toi Cards(FirstIIndex).  If you want to see if they are set to the same thing, just check to see if FirstIIndex = SecondIndex.

Comment: I did end up putting a parallel array that is scrambled at the same time as the image array, just indexing with numbers. Thank you for your answer